# Error getting javascript resource from server

Tags: javascript, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I wrote a plugin for wordpress. It is working fine but on some hosting I get the following error in Firebug

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exampledomain.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/templates/js/lib/jquery.cookie.js?ver=3.5.1"

(The above url is not actual, I replaced the actual domain to exampledomain.com)

As you can see when I request the .js file, server answer me: 404 Not Found

I copied and pasted the whole url on other pc and browser but I still getting the same answer from the server (Apache).

The lib folder (look at the last folder in url) holds other .js file e.g. jquery.scrollTo.js and I can access this file properly. The only file a can't access into this folder is jquery.cookie.js

A wrong .htaccess rule? the file have no read permission on Apache? Any ideas?

Comment: The redirection happens too quickly to see any output, what's in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I change the jquery.cookie.js file name to jquery-cookie.js Maybe, the Web Server (Apache) holds any security rule denying the access to any resource (i.e. file) that contain ".cookie" string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the filename to something obscure, then you can look if a wrong rule kicks in for the name.